# C while-loop not stopping

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("Enter your change: ");
    int pennies = 0, nickels = 0, dimes = 0, quarters = 0;
    float change = GetFloat();

    while (change > 0) {
        if (change >= 0.25) {
            quarters++;
            change -= 0.25;
        }
        else if (change >= 0.10) {
            dimes++;
            change -= 0.10;
        }
        else if (change >= 0.05) {
            nickels++;
            change -= 0.05;
        }
        else if (change >=0.01) {
            pennies++;
            change -= 0.01;
        }
        // force break
        else {
        printf("%1.2f - Num. of change left\n", change);
        break;
        }
    }
    printf("Quarters: %d\n", quarters);
    printf("Dimes: %d\n", dimes);
    printf("Nickels: %d\n", nickels);
    printf("Pennies: %d\n", pennies);
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I'm currently new to C and I'm taking Harvard's CS50 class online. The "change" variable seems to go down to 0.00 without stopping the while-loop. This forced me to type in "break" at the end. What is wrong with my code?

This is from problem set 1 by the way.

Comment: Seriously, `float` to count the *integral* number of cents?!?!

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Thanks for providing links to information you refer to, for instance http://d2o9nyf4hwsci4.cloudfront.net/2012/fall/psets/1/pset1.pdf . Note footnote 9 in this document: “For 
  instance, 
  0.01 
  cannot 
  be 
  represented 
  exactly 
  as 
  a 
  float”

Comment: Can you post the GetFloat() function code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are problems with how floating point numbers are represented in a computer memory. If in short: not all numbers can be stored precisely. Please read this page for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You can use this service to check the representations of floats in a computer: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html

Regarding your case, let's assume you have entered 0.4. That means it should be divided into 0.25 + 0.1 + 0.05. And `change` is supposed to be zero, but:

```
0.40 == 0.4000000059604644775390625000,
 minus
0.25 == 0.2500000000000000000000000000 (exact),
 minus
0.10 == 0.1000000014901161193847656250,
 minus
0.05 == 0.0500000007450580596923828125
 is
0.00 == 0.0000000037252902984619140625
```

As you can see, the final result is slightly above zero, what prevents your loop from ending.

Generally, if you need to count money, you should use `int` instead to count "cents". Or custom types. Or long arithmetic. Or whatever, but not floating points, because money in most countries needs only two positions after a point, thus this point needs not to be *floating*.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use floating point numbers for representing numbers that are integral by nature. Floating point arithmetic is a problem here. `Change` in most cases will never be equal to 0. You should just do everything with integers and it will work. Algorithm looks fine.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is a floating point issue. Here's your problem:

```
else if (change >=0.01) {
            pennies++;
            change -= 0.01;
        }
```

What's probably happening is that `change` ends up very slightly higher than 0.01, so when you subtract 0.01 from it, it ends up being slightly greater than zero, but less than 0.01, and you have no `if` clauses to deal with that eventuality, so it goes on forever. Your `printf()` shows zero because you're rounding it down to two decimal places, so it looks like 0.00 even though it's probably 0.00001 or something.

Answer (score 1):

it isn't wise to use floats for this, as stated a several times here...

**but** logically you can do what you are trying, and I suspect it has to do with comparison and promotion rules in C... but I would guess this will fix your problem:

```
while (change > 0.0f)
```

that way you are comparing like types...

really you should change to using int, long, or long long... and representing cents rather than dollars.

Comment: this I guess will only work if in fact you have enough to get less than zero.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but here's how I'd have written it. It uses `int` rather than `float` to avoid rounding problems, has a table-driven computation for each of the coins, and does division rather than repeated subtraction.

```
int change = GetFloat() * 100 + 0.5;
struct {const char *name; int value;} coins[] = {
    {"Quarters", 25},
    {"Dimes", 10},
    {"Nickels", 5},
    {"Pennies", 1},
};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int coin = change / coins[i].value;
    change %= coins[i].value;
    printf("%s: %d\n", coins[i].name, coin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the integer equivalent of getFloat(), or use an integer variable to do the comparisions. The code is going wrong because of floating point issues.

```
    #include<math.h>  // for round
...
...
    int change = int)100 * round(getFloat());
```

Comment: He will want to multiply that by 100 before rounding and converting to an `int`…